# Physical explanation of seeing sparkles?

Tags: optics, vision, biology, lightning, perception

I know this might look more appropriate to ask this kind of question on the biology or medical stackexchange but since this kind of cross-science question I'll ask it here.

Sometimes when sitting and working on my computer I get to see sparkles which look like particle trajectories. 
Sometimes they look like electron-positron decay going in spiral, sometimes they is just a line, a trace.
 I suppose the nerves that transfer electric signals from the eye to the brain get to interact with some kind of electrical stuff (electrons ? electrons absorbing EM waves ?). This kind of sparkles are different from the ones you would see if you were to hit your head on the ground (or any other childish stuff).

Does anybody knows from where this "electric" perturbations come from ?

Could it be from environmental radiation, like Earth's natural radioactivity, or energetic cosmic beams that reach Earth ?

$dt$ is about 100ms-500ms.

They kind a look like this:
[image]

Or like this:
[image]

Note: this is a question addressed in a rational way and I expect a physical interpretation - if any (= not superstitious stuff. thx)

Comment: Unless you are living somewhere quite odd (space, inside a reactor or something) then this is almost certainly an artifact of something in your optical or nervous system.

Comment: Try an internet search for floaters

Comment: Nope, they are not floaters, the stuff happens exactly like in the pictures i gave, unlike floaters which happen inside vitreous humor. Floater: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Floaters.png

Comment: I believe I know what you're talking about! I looked for the answers myself to this question. It's not being lightheaded and seeing stars, it's not floaters or blood cells, it's also not the lights/colors you see when you close your eyes. It's totally different. I've always thought it looked like seeing your neurons firing somehow. The tiniest little trailing sparkles. I also only see them in bright light when I'm not looking at anything in particular. Does that sound like what you're experiencing as well? If so, I recommend looking into Visual Snow or HPPD. There's different ways it can [..]

Comment: [...] manifest, but one of the ways is the sparks of light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the following Wikipedia page on **phosphenes** and see if any of the possible causes apply to your situation.

"A [phosphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphene) is a phenomenon characterized by the experience of seeing light without light actually entering the eye."

"Phosphenes can be directly induced by mechanical, electrical, or magnetic stimulation of the retina or visual cortex as well as by random firing of cells in the visual system."

Comment: also go see a dr. it is a possible symptom of your retina detaching.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the blood pressure drops.
If you have low blood pressure and get up, the head does not get enough blood.
It can even happen that you faint for a moment.

Comment: This is true in some cases, but in my case I was sitting at the desk, near big windows, working on the laptop, listening to music (earplugs; and the kind of music that gives "adrenaline"). This did happen several times in different days, but only when (all) this conditions were met.

Answer (score 1):

Look up at a bright, blue sky and you may notice tiny dots of moving light. You aren’t imagining these spots. They are created by your own white blood cells flowing through your eyes. What you are experiencing is a very normal occurrence called the blue field entoptic phenomenon.

Blood flows to your eyes through capillaries that pass over the retina — the tissue at the back of your eye that acts as a receptor for all light. Red blood cells, which make up more than 90 percent of your blood, absorb blue light. As these cells move through the capillaries in front of your retina, your eye and brain adjust so that you don’t see shadows or dark spots.

White blood cells flow through the capillaries much less frequently than red blood cells. These larger blood cells let blue light through to your retina. The retina sends a signal of increased brightness to the brain, and, to a viewer looking at the sky or any large monochromatic area, it looks like a tiny spot of white light is moving through the space.

The dots may look like little worms as the bigger white blood cells stretch and elongate to pass through the capillaries. You may also see a dark tail with the dot of light, which is a bunch-up of red blood cells behind the slower-moving white blood cell.

These “blue-sky sprites” normally disappear after a second or less. Their movement may seem squiggly, following the path of the capillaries in your eyes. And their speed varies in time with your pulse, accelerating with your heartbeat.

Don’t confuse the normal blue field entoptic phenomenon (BFEP) with floaters or flashes—which can interfere with your vision and signal a serious eye problem. BFEP lights are all the same size and shape. If the eye stops moving, the spots keep whizzing around.

In contrast, floaters, which are clumps in your vitreous, the gel-like fluid in your eye, differ in size and brightness. If the eye stops moving, the floaters settle down. If the eye moves, the floaters follow more slowly.

Flashes look like lightning streaks or stars, can last for 10 to 20 minutes and may come and go for several weeks or months. If you notice a change in your vision or have a sudden onset of flashes or floaters, please call a doctor right away. New or increased flashes or floaters can be a sign of a retinal detachment.

I hope this answers your question because they do seem to behave like protons.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's a good explanation in case of BFEP. However, it's totally something else from what I've seen. And I was sitting at my desk, working on my laptop (I use low-light on my lcd), listening to music on my standard apple earphones. The 2nd image I provided is very "accurately" similar. It leaves a white track; one single track it's about 1/3 the size of the eye vision.

Comment: The path is continuous, no organic staff can make such a perfect arc of circle; too big, too accurate. I'm more inclined to think they are muons/electrons (and protons I think they are to big to make such curves so easily)